# Linked list, count even and uneven positions, unsing recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I want to create two methods, "private int sumEven (Node node){}" for suming up even positions in a linked list and "sumOdd (Node node) {}" for suming up odd positions. I want to use recursion.

This is how far i've come, but i dont know what should I do next.
Does any one have a tipp or a hint for me, what should i do next?

```
public class RecursiveListTest {
   static Node head;
   static boolean found = false;
   static int counter = 0;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       RecursiveListTest list = new RecursiveListTest();

       list.addNumber(3);
       list.addNumber(5);
       list.addNumber(2);
       list.addNumber(7);
       list.addNumber(5);
       list.addNumber(1);
       list.addNumber(4);
       list.printList();

       int sumEven = list.sumEven(head);
       int sumOdd = list.sumOdd(head);

       System.out.println();
       System.out.println("Sum of even Positions: " + sumEven);
       System.out.println();
       System.out.println("Sum of odd Positions: " + sumOdd);
       System.out.println();
   }

   // Node
   private class Node {
       Node next;
       int value;

       Node(int value, Node next) {
           this.value = value;
           this.next = next;
       }
   }

   private int sumEven(Node n) {
       int sumEven = 0;
       int sumOdd = 0;

       counter = counter + 1;

       if (counter % 2 == 0) {
           sumEven = sumEven + n.value;
           if (n.next.next != null) {
               sumEven = sumEven + sumEven(n.next.next);
           }
       }

       else if (counter % 2 == 1) {
           if (n.next != null) {
               sumEven = sumEven + sumEven(n.next);
           }
       }

       return sumEven;
   }

   private int sumOdd(Node n) {
       return 0;
   }

   private void addNumber(int number) {
       Node curr = head;
       Node prev = null;

       if (head == null) {
           head = new Node(number, null);
       } else {
           while (curr != null) {
               prev = curr;
               curr = curr.next;
           }

           Node newNode = new Node(number, null);
           prev.next = newNode;
       }
   }



   private void printList() {
       Node curr = head;
       Node prev = null;

       while (curr != null) {
           System.out.print(curr.value + " ");

           prev = curr;
           curr = curr.next;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you post code that actually compiles, for starters?  And maybe explain what the code you posted is supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using variables `private static int evenSum, oddSum` and your methods could be:

```
private int sumEven() {

    evenSum = 0;
    sumEvenHelper(head);
    return evenSum;

}

private int sumOdd() {

    oddSum = 0;
    sumEvenHelper(head);
    return oddSum;

}

private void sumEvenHelper(Node n) {

    if(n != null) {

        evenSum += n.value;
        sumOddHelper(n.next);

    }

}

private void sumOddHelper(Node n) {

    if(n != null) {

        oddSum += n.value;
        sumEvenHelper(n.next);

    }

}
```

My code assumes `head` is list element 0. Otherwise you will call `sumOddHelper(head)` inside the `sumEven` and `sumOdd` methods.